# Geospatial application in python using OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented, geospatial

I'm working on a tool that performs some computations using elevations from a DTM file retrieved from a WCS service. These computations will be done on predefined regions of Europe.
I'm trying to encapsulate some things in classes, but it is my first time really using them, so I would love to get some feedback.
Basically I created a `Region` class that contains several attributes and internal methods that connects to the WCS service and handles the response.
Since the regions are predefined, I also created 2 additional classes that store constants: `BboxFlood`, that contains the `BBOX` I want to retrieve from the service (and will be used to do some flooding operations) and `Borders`, which contains the outline of the region (which is the real region of interest). This outline is used to create a mask (`masked_raster`) which I will modify using other functions lately.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
from requests.exceptions import MissingSchema
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService
from owslib.util import ServiceException
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
from rasterio.errors import RasterioIOError
from rasterio.plot import show
from geopandas import read_file
from rasterio.features import geometry_mask
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from fiona.errors import DriverError


class Region():
    
    
    def __init__(self, name, bbox, epsg, outline):
        """
        Create a region of interest

        Parameters
        ----------
        name : str
            Region name.
        bbox : tuple or list
            Bounding box of the region
        epsg : str
            Spatial reference system
        outline : shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon or str, optional
            A shapely Polygon defining the border of the region of interest.
            Alternatively, a path to the shapefile. 
            NOTE: The outline epsg should coincide with the raster one.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
            
        self.name = name
        self.bbox = bbox
        self.epsg = epsg
        self.outline = outline
        
        self.raster = None
        self.masked_raster = None
        self.mask = None
        
        self.profile = None
        self.transform = None
        self.resx = None
        self.resy = None
        
        if isinstance(outline, str):
            self._read_outline(outline)
            
         
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Region: {self.name}, Bbox: {self.bbox}, EPSG: {self.epsg}"
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Region({self.name!r}, {self.bbox!r}, {self.epsg!r})"
        
    
    def _get_bytes_from_response(self, wcs_response):
        """
        Get tif file from multipart response from DV

        Parameters
        ----------
        wcs_response : owslib.util.ResponseWrapper
            wcs response after getCoverage

        Returns
        -------
        image_bytes : bytes
            image file in bytes

        """

        boundary = b"--wcs"
        
        bytes_parts = wcs_response.read().split(boundary)
        
        for part in bytes_parts:
            
            if part.startswith(b"\nContent-Type: image/tiff"):
                index = part.index(b"II*")
                image_bytes = part[index:]
                break
        
        
        return image_bytes
    
    
    def _bytes_to_raster(self, response_as_bytes):
        # This internal method is used to read the response retrieved from 
        # the WCS service
                
        try:
            # Create a file in memory not to write any file to the hard disk
            with MemoryFile(response_as_bytes) as memfile:
                with memfile.open() as src:
                    raster = src.read(1)
                    profile = src.profile
                    res = src.res
                      
        except RasterioIOError() as e:
            print("Rasterio error:", e)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print('Unexpected error:', e)

        else:
            self.raster = raster
            self.profile = profile
            self.transform = profile['transform']
            self.resx = res[0]
            self.resy = res[1]
            
            
    def _read_outline(self, outline_path):
        # Read outline from path if not given as a Polygon
        try:
            gdf = read_file(outline_path)
     
        except DriverError as e:
            print("Incorrect file name:", e)
            
        else:
            self.outline = gdf.geometry.iloc[0]
    
    
    def _set_masked_raster(self):
        # Create a masked version of the raster based on outline
        mask = geometry_mask([mapping(self.outline)],
                             out_shape=self.raster.shape,
                             transform=self.transform,
                             invert=True
                             )

        self.mask = ~mask
        self.masked_raster = np.where(mask, 
                                      self.raster, 
                                      self.profile['nodata'])
        

    def get_dtm_from_wcs_201(self, 
                         raster_source='https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/DHMV/wcs',
                         layer='DHMVII_DTM_1m', 
                         format='image/tiff',
                         version="2.0.1",
                         scalefactor=3):
        """
        Get raster and metadata from a WCS service

        Parameters
        ----------
        raster_source : str, optional
            URL of WCS service.
        layer : str, optional
            CoverageID.
        format : str, optional
            File type of the request. The default is 'image/tiff'.
        version : str, optional
            Version of the WCS protocol. The default is "2.0.1".
        scalefactor : int, optional
            Scale. The default is 3.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """      
        
        sset = [('x', self.bbox[0], self.bbox[2]), ('y', self.bbox[1], self.bbox[3])]
        
        try: 
            # Connect to WCS and try getting a coverage
            wcs = WebCoverageService(raster_source, version=version)
            response = wcs.getCoverage(identifier=[layer],
                                       bbox=self.bbox,
                                       crs=self.epsg,
                                       subsets=sset,
                                       format=format,
                                       scalefactor=scalefactor, 
                                       )
            
        except MissingSchema as e:
            print('Invalid URL:', e)
            
        except ServiceException as e:
            print("Service error:", e)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print("An unexpected error has ocurred", e)
        
        else:
            image_bytes = self._get_bytes_from_response(response)
            self._bytes_to_raster(image_bytes)
            self._set_masked_raster()
                
    
    def reset_masked_raster(self):
        self._set_masked_raster()



from shapely.geometry import Polygon

class BboxFlood():
   
    ROMBOUT = {'bbox': (71274, 213729, 75273, 219336), 
                     'epsg': 'EPSG:31370'}

class Borders():
    
    ROMBOUT = {'outline': Polygon([(71275.24244585728, 214206.7075793226),
                                    (71332.89192388157, 214301.1237481891),
                                    (71451.59618105175, 214522.12153573174),
                                    (71542.7001391952, 214700.03943770562),
                                    (71605.07543163445, 214832.82320418613),
                                    (71750.3815106122, 215099.33581733558),
                                    (71788.18471815114, 215162.6561899633),
                                    (71811.33918276873, 215193.37129608868),
                                    (71853.86779125003, 215234.00974419303),
                                    (71886.47305775236, 215265.19739041265),
                                    (71909.15498227572, 215310.56123945938),
                                    (71914.82546340655, 215363.9582701081),
                                    (71920.02340444316, 215416.88276066261),
                                    (71928.05658604519, 215456.57612857848),
                                    (71937.50738792992, 215485.40107432692),
                                    (71965.38725348988, 215542.1058856353),
                                    (72009.33348225389, 215614.87706014776),
                                    (72072.18131478736, 215710.8026992778),
                                    (72097.69847987614, 215755.69400823026),
                                    (72152.04059071335, 215863.43314971623),
                                    (72178.03029589636, 215913.99493979954),
                                    (72187.95363787533, 215954.6333879039),
                                    (72195.04173928888, 215999.05215676213),
                                    (72187.4810977811, 216064.2626897668),
                                    (72169.99711429434, 216140.81418503314),
                                    (72168.57949401163, 216214.0578996398),
                                    (72180.86553646179, 216347.31420621453),
                                    (72189.84379825227, 216402.128857146),
                                    (72197.8769798543, 216429.53618261172),
                                    (72221.97652466036, 216482.93321326046),
                                    (72264.26886309455, 216559.01216843256),
                                    (72300.18191025654, 216626.58540190838),
                                    (72334.20479704157, 216687.54307406492),
                                    (72368.22768382661, 216733.8520033001),
                                    (72415.95423334451, 216787.72157404307),
                                    (72501.95653049558, 216866.16322968635),
                                    (72556.77118142703, 216924.28566127748),
                                    (72574.25516491377, 216948.8577461778),
                                    (73971.55622357152, 219165.54332824182),
                                    (74158.68210088921, 219335.65776216701),
                                    (74694.54256775357, 218468.07414914857),
                                    (74856.1512799825, 218306.46543691962),
                                    (75272.9316430992, 217991.75373415803),
                                    (72559.60642199244, 214402.33917833655),
                                    (71726.04569575902, 213730.38716433206),
                                    (71275.24244585728, 214206.7075793226)]),
                 'epsg':'EPSG:31370'}


# Example

rombout = Region("Romb", **BboxFlood.ROMBOUT, 
                  outline=Borders.ROMBOUT['outline'])
    
rombout.get_dtm_from_wcs_201(scalefactor=5)
```

I have another module that contains functions that takes a region as parameter (they modify the `masked_raster` attribute)
What do you think? Is it well-structured? One of my biggest concern is how to test it (I have been doing it manually).
Any feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)
asks that you organize your imports, perhaps with
[$ isort *.py](https://pypi.org/project/isort).
That delayed Polygon import is certainly a surprise.

## class documentation

```
class Region():
```

You passed up the opportunity to write a """docstring""" telling us the
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
of this class.
It comes in handy a month down the road when you're
tempted to add a `kitchen_sink` attribute or method,
and then upon reading the docstring you realize
the new thing belongs in a new class
that has a different responsibility.

Dunno what those empty `()` brackets are doing there.
Makes it look like we have a python2 "new style" class
that inherits from `object`.
Just elide them.

## signature should match docs

You assert that `outline` is "optional".
No, it's not.
Caller will get a TypeError if it's missing.

Recommend you give it a keyword default of `None`.

The `epsg` description is helpful, thank you.
But a naïve human would find it more helpful if "WGS84"
was mentioned as a valid value, so we know that
uppercase is OK and that "4326" is not what it's looking for.

Even better, leave the docstring alone and give the signature
a keyword default of `"WGS84"`.

```
    def __init__(self, name, bbox, epsg, outline):
        """
        Create a region of interest

        Parameters
        ----------
        name : str
            Region name.
        bbox : tuple or list
            Bounding box of the region
        epsg : str
            Spatial reference system
        outline : shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon or str, optional
```

You *can* tell humans about types in that way.
But it's better to tell humans + `mypy`:

```
    def __init__(self, name: str, bbox: tuple | list,
                 epsg: str, outline: Polygon | str | None):
```

> Alternatively, a path to the shapefile.

It makes me sad that you chose to use generic `str` rather than `Path`
to model the concept of a pathname.

> Returns ... None.

We *can* end the signature annotation with `-> None:`.
But I usually elide that on `__init__` ctors,
since it's obvious to both man and machine.
It's certainly helpful on other methods and on `def main() -> None:`.
No need for "None" in the docstring.

I *do* thank you for the "table of contents",
where you assign `raster` through `resy` attributes.

## tuple vs list

```
        bbox : tuple or list
```

That should be just "tuple", please.

In python we use a `list` for "zero-or-more of same thing",
and a `tuple` for "fixed number of different things" which
can have different types. A tuple is like a C struct.
Here, `bbox[0]` means something entirely different
from `bbox[3]` -- the meaning comes from the position.
And it's not like a `list` of five numbers would be valid.

Even nicer would be to define a `Bbox`
[named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).
Then instead of cryptic `[3]` subscripts
we could use (abbreviated) names for the elements.

## assign from helper

The ctor ends with

```
        if isinstance(outline, str):
            self._read_outline(outline)
```

Prefer

```
        if isinstance(outline, str):
            self.outline = self._read_outline(outline)
```

and then the helper ends with `return gdf.geometry.iloc[0]`.

It makes the side effect obvious,
rather than hoping the reader will infer a side effect
from the spelling of the helper's name.

## errors should be fatal

```
    def _read_outline(self, outline_path):
        ...     
        except DriverError as e:
            print("Incorrect file name:", e)
```

Either don't catch DriverError,
or wrap `e` and re-raise it with that helpful "incorrect..." diagnostic.
As it stands we print() and move on *as if* `self.outline`
contained something useful.
That's just kicking the can down the road, so some *other*
method will get blamed for a fatal error.
Accept the blame *here*, to expedite diagnosis and bug fixes.

Also, consider making `f"{outline_path}"` part of the diagnostic,
for quicker diagnosis.

## meaningful identifiers

```
    def _get_bytes_from_response(self, wcs_response):
        """
        Get tif file from multipart response from DV
```

This is pretty good.

Much of the docstring would be superfluous if it was named

```
    def _get_image_from_coverage( ... ) -> bytes:
```

I don't know what "DV" denotes, but that's ok.

Consider using the variant spelling of "tiff", or "TIFF",
given that we're not talking about a *.tif file extension here.

```
        bytes_parts = wcs_response.read().split(boundary)
```

It would be enough to just call this `parts`.
Add an annotation if you feel that `bytes` isn't clear to the reader.

```
            if part.startswith(b"\nContent-Type: image/tiff"):
```

This is on the fragile side.
Yes, I understand that WCS uses *this* spelling ATM.
The header case could change yet it would mean the same thing.
Consider case smashing to `.lower()` before the comparison.

## docstring rather than comment

This is good.

```
    def _bytes_to_raster( ... ):
        # This internal method is used to read the response retrieved from 
        # the WCS service
```

It would be better if it appeared in """docstring""" form,
just a single English sentence.
(And then add a type annotation, please.)

```
        except RasterioIOError() as e:
            print("Rasterio error:", e)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print('Unexpected error:', e)
```

No, no, please just let those bubble up the call stack as fatal.
As it stands, you're swallowing the exception, carrying on,
and not even showing a maintenance engineer the source line number
in a stack trace.

## a new dataclass

This is kind of interesting:

```
        else:
            self.raster = raster
            self.profile = profile
            self.transform = profile['transform']
            self.resx = res[0]
            self.resy = res[1]
```

There's an atomic all-or-nothing aspect to this,
as if you were concerned de-referencing the `src.profile`
or `src.res` properties could `raise`.

Up in the ctor I was thinking "gosh, seems like there's
a *bunch* of attributes on this object."
This stanza of five assignments suggests that maybe
we should hang onto a single `self.raster` object,
which in turn has five attributes.
The [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)
decorator is your friend.

The `(mask, masked_raster)` tuple might be viewed in a similar light.

## good defaults

I found `get_dtm_from_wcs_201()` extremely clear,
thank you for those helpful default values.
The "dtm" part is obscure, so the only part of
the docstring I really need is where it explains
that a DTM is apparently raster + metadata.

Also `layer` is perhaps really a `layer_id`.

Usual grumble: things like `MissingSchema` and `ServiceException`
should re-raise as fatal.

## new module

The ROMBOUT data dump
should probably go in a new `rombout.py` module.

## "**main**" guard

```
rombout.get_dtm_from_wcs_201(scalefactor=5)
```

Please use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom, so e.g. a
[unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
could safely `import` this.

---

This code achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

---

EDIT

> I read somewhere that for private methods commenting instead of docstring was the standard.

I suspect someone had tooling that would accidentally add
`_my_helper` to published ReadTheDocs web pages
if it had a docstring.

Most folks use `sphinx`, which by default won't do that.
I've never seen that it's a concern.

Every method, whether it's part of your Public API or not,
has a specification, a contract.
It can be poorly specified and implicit.
Or you can use a clear English sentence to
spell it out in a docstring.
We want to know its
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
We want to know what it *promises* will be true upon `return`.
A docstring is an excellent way to communicate that
to your colleagues.
For `public()` and for `_private()` methods.

> The DTM is a digital terrain model. I will change.

No biggie.
I mean, I knew that it was some Term of Art,
and I knew that I wasn't familiar enough with the literature
but probably a maintenance engineer a few months
from now *would* be. So I wasn't worried.
I was just offering that a `#` comment which expands the
[TLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym)
would have been welcome, is all.
And sure, getting elevation would be a helpful phrase
in the identifier.

> Use "tiff", or "TIFF",

It was just a spelling nit I was quibbling over.
We say `*.tif` in a comment when talking about file extensions.
But we say "tiff", or more properly "TIFF",
when we mean Tagged Image File Format.
(There's no such thing as TIF.)

> I didn't understand the dataclass part neither. You meant making other classes?

Yes.

In OO design we look for nouns, "objects",
that exist in the Business Domain and that
we can model within the machine.
Now, a noun could be "big", like a `Kitchen`
and all it contains.
Or our modeling could be more granular,
and we might model a `Stove`, a `Microwave`,
and so on.

Your `Region` has eleven attributes,
which isn't *necessarily* Too Many,
but it's a code smell, it's starting
to look a little on the big side.
It makes you wonder whether there could be some **grouping**
of things, which collectively are their own thing.

So when I got down to that atomic assignment
of five attributes I said "Aha!", I had been looking
for such an opportunity, and maybe I just found it.
Now, it's up to you.
I don't know what makes the most sense in your environment.
But I offered it as something to consider -- maybe you'd
like to group them together.
And similarly for that masking 2-tuple.

## assignment vs side-effect

If a ctor is creating a `House` object, I would much rather see

```
        self.kitchen = self._get_kitchen( ... )
```

than

```
        self._build_kitchen( ... )
```

Now, maybe the "side effect" aspect of that helper is
apparent from the name.
But I worry that it might update `self.plumbing`
and some other things.
Plus, it's hard to
[unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
If I *can* reveal the side effecting via an assignment like that,
it will be my preference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I really appreciate it.
- I forgot to explain that the Polygon import is because I have BboxFlood and Borders already in another .py
- I read somewhere that for private methods commenting instead of docstring was the standard.
- What should I do with the fatal errors? Make the program crash?
- The DTM is a digital terrain model. I will change. Maybe get_elevation_from_wcs201 is better?
- Use "tiff", or "TIFF", I didn't understand what you meant there
- I didn't understand the dataclass part neither. You meant making other classes?
Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

## manifesto

Code should be bug-free.

[Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
is one path toward that.
It promotes **composability** of components.

> What should I do with the fatal errors? Make the program crash?

Yes.

Or make it do the Right Thing, if you prefer.
(The current implementation just ignores the error and stumbles forward.)

## total function

A function is **specified** to accept inputs and
produce some result: return value and/or side effects.

The inputs can be explicit in the signature,
they can also be global variables,
filesystem fullness, wallclock time,
[PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)
state, and so on.

Some functions are
[total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) --
they will always produce a correct result, for any input.
Here is one, in python:

```
def increment(n: int) -> int:
    return n + 1
```

Assuming we can malloc() and the power is on,
this function pretty much always returns what you expect,
when given the proper object type.

Here is a similar function in C:

```
uchar increment(uchar n) {
    return n + 1;
}
```

Calling `increment(254)` does the Right Thing.
But probably the caller is being too adventurous
upon supplying an unsigned arg of `255`.
For modulo operations this is well defined,
but if the contract is to "return a bigger number",
then this is a partial function.
If this were C++ we might choose to throw an exception for that.

The familiar `sqrt()` function offers a similar example.
If we rule out `NaN` and complex / imaginary numbers,
then caller should avoid offering a negative argument.
This is called a pre-condition on acceptable inputs.
If we *do* see negative input,
it is appropriate for `sqrt` to immediately `raise` a fatal error
so caller will fix their broken code.

## post-condition

The contract for the root finder looks like this:
"Give me a non-negative real.
I *promise* to hand back a real which, when squared,
equals the original argument."
(We are in FP-land, here, so we finesse "equals"
to mean "low relative error", typically specified
by some `epsilon` parameter.)

Now, in a case like `sqrt(-3)`, there is simply
no way to fulfill that contract.
What should the root finder do?
Return a sentinel like `99`?
(Nevermind that it's indistinguishable from `sqrt(9801)`.)
Maybe "better" sentinel values happen to be
available, like `-99`?
Sure, that's *one* possibility that folks have tried.
It makes the contract more complex,
and some callers will forget to check for that condition.
Or, we could throw up our hands!

The much better alternative, when faced with an "impossible" contract,
is to give up, with `raise`.
Did we return some `float` value?
No.
We returned nothing, the computation didn't happen.

Throwing an exception interrupts the flow so caller
won't accidentally trust some arbitrary sentinel value
as being "correct".
It *might* be a fatal exception, which halts with a stack trace.
Or the caller *might* have anticipated this situation,
and have some strategy for coping with it.
Caller might try an alternative call (flip the sign),
or pause while it asks a human for help,
or re-`raise` so *its* higher level caller
is aware of the situation.

> Make the program crash?

Yes. Or no.
It's not your
[responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
A pre-condition wasn't satisfied or you
can't make your post-condition true for whatever reason,
so you bail out and make the caller aware of it.
What the caller does is up to him, it's not your job.